# Label of an option have to change when the select is open and close

Tags: javascript, select, dom-events

I have a select with an option selected by default "Select an element" (some sort of place holder)

I want that when the user open the select, the label of this option switch to "I don't want to select anything". (The other labels of the option list appear too) And if the user change this mind and select "I don't  ..." , the list of option close and the label come back to "Select an element".

I think I could use:

```
onclick=event.target[0].text="I don't want select anything"
onchange=event.target[0].text="Select an element"
```

but the `onclick` event is called after the open of the option list.

my select: when the list is closed

```
<select>
  <option value="0"selected > Select an element</option>
  <option value="1">element 1</option>
  <option value="2">element 1</option>
</select>
```

When the list is open:

```
<select>
  <option value="0 >I don't want select anything</option>
  <option value="1">element 1</option>
  <option value="2">element 1</option>
</select>
```

Any Idea?

Maybe there is an event who can be call **before** the open of the select's list

Comment: Why would you do this?  Why do you need to have a `<select>` but not allow the user to change it?

Comment: I have other normal options, than the user can select. I just have one "empty" option.

Comment: Why not just set the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: The option will still be visible by the user.

Comment: This seems like poor interface design.  What information are you showing the user?  Why are you showing it in a `<select>`?  Why should they be unable to change it?

Comment: The user, after a click on the "Select an element", change his mind and decide to "Don't select anything."

Comment: The select element already has that functionality.  When the user clicks off the element or otherwise causes it to lose focus, it will revert.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it: I have to use onmousedown instead of onclick

```
onmousedown=event.target[0].text="I don't want select anything"
onchange=event.target[0].text="Select an element"
```